# VS Code Latex Syntax in Markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, latex, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I am currently writing a document with pandoc markdown and therefore use latex syntax.

How can I get Latex support (autocomplete, syntax highlighting, etc.) while writing in a `.md` file?

The Latex Workshop extension works fine for `.tex` files but I couldn't find an option to add file types.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After being troubled by this problem for a long time, I have found a solution.

1. Install Latex Workshop Extension https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop

   - This extension provides a set of language grammar called `markdown_latex_combined`, defined at https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/blob/master/package.json#L158, which does exactly what you are looking for.
2. Switch the Language Mode (right corner in your vscode) of your markdown files from `Markdown` to `markdown_latex_combined`.
3. Profit :D

Answer (score 3):

[Markdown All in One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one#math) provides LaTeX (in fact KaTeX) autocomplete, syntax highlighting.