# How do I get code highlights and autocomplete for Latex code in R Markdown in VSCode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am writing an `.Rmd` file in VSCode using the VSCode [R extension](https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R).  The extension does a great job of highlighting and code completing `r` code inside code chunks.  However, it does not highlight, or code complete, inline Latex code.

For example, this is how my inline Latex code looks like:

[image]

Now, if I change the language mode from R Markdown to Markdown as indicated in this question [VS Code Latex Syntax in Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65920958/vs-code-latex-syntax-in-markdown), then I get great Latex code highlighting and completion, as shown below:

[image]

However, when I do this I loose all highlights and completion for the `r` code inside the code chunks.

How do I set things up so that I have highlights and code completion for code chunks and inline Latex code?

Comment: "_However, when I do this I loose all highlights and completion for the r code inside the code chunks._" what code chunks? Ones inside triple backticks (code fences)?

Comment: Yes, the standard R Markdown code chunks of the sort ```{r} ... ```